# How only numeric soft keypad will show in android

Tags: android

There is a field that is ZIPCODE.when I click on it then it should be open softkeypad for numeric.is it possible.how??

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that in `XML` you need to put in your `EditText` : `android:inputType="number"` or in code you can do something like this on your edit text: `editText.setInputType(InputType.NUMBER);`

Good luck!

Comment: in your emulator in settings ->keyboard check what are the keypads checked. you need to disable other language keypad. if thats your problem. otherwise inputtype=number should work. test it in a device and see.

Comment: Some manufacturers use a non stock keyboard that does not always respect the InputType requests. If you think you have done everything correctly and the numeric keypad still does not display, try using "Hackers Keyboard" from Android Market. It works correctly so will show if it is your code or your keyboard that is doing it wrong.

Comment: No..its ok..thank you so much it is working properly..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

in xml give for the edittext give `android:inputType="number"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the [**`android:inputType`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute on your field, to indicate it should allow the user to type numbers *(using a value of **`number`**)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="1234567890"
```

may help you